# insertar el mismo atributo a todas mis bases de datos en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Buenas alguien podría decirme como hacer para insertar 1 atributo a todas mis bases de datos en mysql, por ejemplo supongamos que tengo 30 bases de datos ya hechas, pero derrepente se me ocurrió agregarle un atributo nuevo a las bases de datos, entonces para no comenzar 1 base de datos por 1 base de datos usando

```
use empresa1;

alter table informacion_empresa1,

add Observacion varchar(500)
```

---

```
use empresa2;

alter table informacion_empresa2,

add Observacion varchar(500)
```

---

```
use empresa3;

alter table informacion_empresa3,

add Observacion varchar(500)
```

como pueden ver el unico atributo que se agregará es (Observacion)

pero para no hacer eso de a 1 en 1 hasta llegar a las 30 bses de datos no hay algo que lo haga automatico?

algo así como

```
use empresa1,empresa2,empresa3,empresa4,empresa5,empresa6,empresa7 etc

    alter table informacion_empresa1,informacion_empresa2,informacion_empresa3,informacion_empresa4etc 

    add Observacion varchar(500)
```

o algo asi que me ahorre todo el trabajo espero haberme explicado bien,

Comment: Si son 30 bases de datos no te merece la pena crear un script para esto. Puedes escribir las 30 consultas con *copy/paste*, cambias los nombres y las ejecutas todas juntas. Si fueran 200 o 1000 bases de datos entonces sí podrías pensar en un script.  Y, es un poco raro que tengas BD que parecen idénticas.

Comment: si la cosa es que la veo negra escribir añadir 1 solo atributo a 30 bases de datos manualmente y eso me seguirá subiendo hasta 5.000 o más y no quiero que cuando tenga esa cantidad se me ocurre insertar un atributo nuevo y después comenzar de nuevo de 1 por 1 ._.

Comment: ¿5.000 bases de datos? Debe ser algo de la NASA o algo así... ¿Por qué 5,000 bases de datos y que además admitirían atributos a posteriori?

Comment: JAja es que cada base de datos es 1 persona que carga sus atributos es por eso xd

Comment: Pero no, no deberías dedicar una base de datos a una persona. Una base de datos puede albergar muchísimas tablas. A lo sumo podrías asignar una tabla a cada persona, o incluso puedes usar una sola tabla `persona` para todas las personas y guardar sus datos en filas distintas.

Comment: Es qué ya intenté hacerlo como dices y no me sale lo que quiero hacer :/ no tienes por donde mostrarte lo que estoy haciendo?

Comment: El hecho de que no lo hayas logrado no quiere decir que no se pueda. Además afrontar eso con bases de datos distintas es una locura. Una base de datos sirve para almacenar muchas tablas de muchos tipos, generalmente con relación (o no) entre ellas. Si tú creas BD por cada persona, cuando necesites por ejemplo saber datos de varias personas al mismo tiempo  va a ser tremendo. O si necesitas saber cuántas personas se llaman `Pepe` en tu aplicación, vas a tener que conectar a 5,000 bases de datos para encontrar a 3 `Pepe` donde los haya. Cualquier duda la puedes plantear por aquí.

Comment: por dónde podría mostrate lo que estoy haciendo mano, como me contacto contigo?

Comment: Mano la verdad es que es como llevarle la contabilidad a personas diferentes de sus empresas